# MYSQL UPDATE with WHERE= is not selecting the correct entries

Tags: mysql

My database code is

```
SELECT `Title`,`Rating`,`Times_Played` from audio WHERE 'Username'='Hamburger7'
```

There are no entries where the username is equal to `Hamburger7`, but it selects two entries anyway. Instead of choosing entries that match the condition, it chooses the ones that are equal to `'0'`, (as opposed to NULL).

The output on my PHP admin page, where the server settings are, is:

```
SELECT  `Title` ,  `Rating` ,  `Times_Played` 
FROM audio
WHERE  `Username` =  'Hamburger7'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: why are you using a select statement to perform an **update**?

Comment: btw 'Username' = 'Hamburger7' always fail because **you are comparing two different constants** (strings), you should compare a field with the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have `Username` in single quotes in the query, which means that you MySQL sees it as a literal string and not a column name.

```
SELECT `Title`,`Rating`,`Times_Played` from audio WHERE 'Username'='Hamburger7'
```

Change it to

```
SELECT `Title`,`Rating`,`Times_Played` from audio WHERE `Username`='Hamburger7'
```

Or better still

```
SELECT Title,Rating,Times_Played from audio WHERE Username='Hamburger7'
```

because you **don't need to put column names in backticks** unless the column name is a reserved word, and making your column names the same as reserved words is a Bad Idea anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. Still, when changing it to that, it doesn't work. Instead, it recalls every entry where the `Username` is equal to `0`

Comment: Then what you have posted in your original entry is not the code that you are running.  Please double check it and maybe even update the original question with a cut & paste of your current code and the progress you've made.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I found the problem was that the username field was set to INT, rather than VARCHAR. Thank you for confirming this. It helped me identity what was not the problem. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `Title`,`Rating`,`Times_Played` from audio WHERE `Username`='Hamburger7'
```

your comparing the string Username to the string Hamburger7 not the column username

Comment: When enclosed in backticks, `Username` will be interpreted as an identifier. Given that the statement is not throwing an exception, it's likely the name of a column in the `audio` table.

Answer (score 1):

The datatype of the `Username` column is a numeric type, probably INT. But definitely not CHAR or VARCHAR.

MySQL is converting your string literal `'Hamburger7'` into a datatype that matches the column. And that converts to 0 in terms of INT.

Your query is effectively:

```
WHERE  `Username` = convert_string_literal_to_integer('Hamburger7')
```

which is equivalent to

```
WHERE  `Username` = 0
```

(Oh the joys of convenient, implicit datatype conversions!)